# MySQL - Select comparando campos da mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sei que deve ser simples, mas estou com dificuldade pra resolver isso.
Tenho uma tabela chamada "empreendimento". Nessa tabela, tenho 4 campos específicos que armazenam diferentes ID's de outros registros dessa mesma tabela.

Exemplo da tabela empreendimento. 
    Os valores dos campos não seguem essa mesma ordem, foi apenas para exemplificar:

```
 id      relacionado1   relacionado2    relacionado3    relacionado4
 10      15             16              17              18
 15      10             16              17              18
 16      15             10              17              18
 17      15             16              10              18
```

Eu preciso fazer um select, mostrando por exemplo, todos os registros com id igual aos campos das tabelas relacionado1, relacionado2, relacionado3, relacionado4.

Como consigo fazer isso? Não estou conseguindo de nenhuma maneira. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: me explique porque você salva os dados de diferentes ID's de outros registros dessa mesma tabela? Essa é a única forma de fazer o que precisa?

Comment: Está meio difícil de entender o que deseja. Creio que sua modelagem de dados não foi bem feita. Por acaso você quer as linhas da tabela aonde os campos relacionado1, relacionado2, relacionado3 e relacionado4 sejam iguais? Coloque em seu exemplo dados que forneçam um retorno esperado e qualseria ele.

Comment: Considerando que é mero `WHERE valor = relacionado1 AND valor = relacionado 2` ou mesmo `WHERE relacionado1 = relacionado2 AND relacionado2 = relacionado3 AND ...`, seria importante [edit] colocando a tentativa e descrevendo o que deu errado para vermos onde está o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde você pode fazer um  select colocando apelidos na tabela, como por exemplo.

```
id      relacionado1   relacionado2    relacionado3    relacionado4
10      15             16              17              18
15      10             16              17              18
16      15             10              17              18
17      15             16              10              18
```

```sql
Select  relacionado1  , relacionado2 from  empreendimento A
inner join empreendimento B
ON a.relacionado1 = b.relacionado2
WHERE a.relacionado=10
```

dessa forma  ira trazer os ids   Retorno da consulta

```
relacionado1   relacionado2    
10             10
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilize `Inner Join` para realizar a comparação:

http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-inner-join-consultar-dados-em-duas-ou-mais-tabelas-29/

Por exemplo:

```
select 
   EP.COLUNA_ID AS ID,
   EP.COLUNA_2,
   EP.COLUNA_3,
   R1.COLUNA_N,
   R2.COLUNA_N
from empreendimento ep
INNER JOIN RELACIONADO1 R1 
  ON(R1.ID = EP.ID)
INNER JOIN RELACIONADO2 R2
  ON(R2.ID = EP.ID)
```